# Cloud9 and ansible

Tags: cloud9-ide, ansible

when trying to run ansible on cloud9,
some of my task have:
sudo_user: emr-user

**HOSTS** file:

`[development]
localhost ansible_connection=local ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu`

**Running with:**
`ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml --limit=development`

keeps failing on this task with:
`failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
[sudo via ansible, key=zacflhyhixxhiajrlmtitjxgpxqimnmn] password:`

I believe it is related to the fact the cloud9 runs on password-less ubuntu root

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the task definition that fails, the output (with -vvvv ideally) and also what Ansible version you are using? Also editing your answer to include the output with -vvvv from running the playbook will help to show why it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to bypass it using `sudo su` and then running:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml --limit=development`

but it doesn't feel right. any other ideas?